# How to send POST variables with Nipple on NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use nipple to post to an url within my nodejs application, which itself is running on hapi.js

The documentation essentially doesn't seem to spell it out.

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/nipple)

I tried passing it as payload inside options but that, while not returning an error, returns a 400. Can someone provide a correct example doing a post using nipple?

Essentially, I have two variables that I need to send - let's call the var1 and var2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That link says that the project has been renamed to wreck. On wreck's github, several of the tests are for a post requests, including this one:

https://github.com/hapijs/wreck/blob/master/test/index.js#L68

If you are still scratching your head, you could also try using curl or postman to sanity check your URL, regardless of any nipple/wreck errors. If that also gives you a 400, nipple/wreck may not be the culprit.

Comment: Reading tests is a great way to learn about libraries when the documentation doesn't cut it, that's helped me out endless times. Hope it works for you.

Comment: After all, I am still not able to send POST data. I wrote a separate response handler in PHP on a different server. I can GET parameters passed in the URL, but nothing is coming in through POST.